# How to run activity from 3rd party library?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am in a non-activity class. In this place I want to run the activity from a 3rd party library which I attached to my project. I have written some code which I thought will do it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(THIRD_PARTY_ACTIVITY.REPORT_EXTRA, parts.toString());
Activity activity = new THIRD_PARTY_ACTIVITY();
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

This code compiles successful but when I execute it, I get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object 
>   reference

How can I run activity from a 3rd party library?

Comment: You can accept the activity variable when calling the method.   Accept it as a parameter. And then use it to start the new screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  You NEVER create an Activity with new.  It won't initialize correctly.  Instead, you create an Intent to launch that Activity and call context.startActivity() to create and launch it.

```
void launchThirdPartyActivity(Context context) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, THIRD_PARTY_ACTIVITY.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

That should work if the activity is in a library.  If you're trying to launch an Activity in another app on the device, you'd use one of the other Intent constructors (which one depends on how/what you're trying to launch-  a specific activity in a specific app?  An activity that can perform an action (like share or view) on a specific data type?  Something else?)

Answer (score 0):

In your library you can do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Here you need to set the ACTION or the COMPONENT in the Intent
//  so that Android knows which Activity you want to start
// Also, you need to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK because you aren't calling
//  startActivity() on an Activity Context
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(THIRD_PARTY_ACTIVITY.REPORT_EXTRA, parts.toString());
Application.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```